# Varnish 7.2 CLI telnet logs

Tags: varnish, centos8

I upgraded to varnish 7.2 and now it dumps the logs of varnishd into /var/log/messages on Centos 8 and can not figure out how to change the location of its logs! any clue would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the log:
varnishd[2327]: CLI telnet ::1 54416 ::1 38535 Wr 200 Backend name ****

Comment: The varnish rpms in CentOS include a `varnishncsa` service that logs to the system journal (and from there to `/var/log/messages` given an appropriate syslog configuration). Maybe you have that or some other `varnishlog` service running?

Comment: varnishncsa is running and it logs separately and working as intended; Since the upgrade to varnish 7.2 the CLI telnet log starting to appear in /var/log/messages; there is no other varnishlog service running, I was thinking to include the log path in the systemd varnish config, but not sure about that and could not find anything in Varnish 7.2 docs about the loging of varnishd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around was to create a varnish config for syslog to place the log file into the desired path so it would not put it into message.